# Can I use RefreshIndicator in Stateless flutter widget?

Tags: flutter, statefulwidget, statelesswidget, flutter-state

I'm fetching some json data from the internet and displaying in a listview builder inside a stateless widget

Now I want to refresh the data using RefreshIndicator.
Do I need a stateful widget for this or can I manage to do this with a stateless widget?

**My understanding**:

If I don't need to refresh, I load the data from internet only on the app start up, So Stateless widget is enough

If I need to refresh, it involves user input, but I don't need to manage a state, I just need to re-run the build method (Which I plan to do by Navigating to the same page, in the onRefresh parameter of RefreshIndicator)

So do I need a stateful widget?

Answer (score 1):

You must change the StatelessWidget to a StatefullWidget and use the function setState (){} to

Comment: Yes, I am using a statefulWidget with setState as of right now.
But the fact that I don't actually need a state (Cause I'm not storing anything, Just loading things from internet) and am still using a StatefulWidget bothers me.

Cause I heard it's a best practise to keep the number of StatefulWidgets to minimum.

For my case, I want to be able to re-run the build method when user performs refresh without using a StatefulWidget

Comment: I understand, but StatefullWidget is using when u need to rebuild the page to loading things from the internet again , not only to store data.

Comment: Got it @GonzaG .Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you need a RefreshIndicator to get again the jsondata from the internet you must need a StateFullWidget because u need to rebuild the page with the newdata. 
There is no point in showing the indicator if you are not going to ask for new information.

Answer (score 0):

Because you want to reduce the **StatefulWidget** instances, you can delegate the task of fetching data to a parent stateful widget.
You could pass a callback to perform the task of fetching data via the constructor of the **StatelessWidget** invoked whenever we want to refresh the data.

```dart
  class _ParentWidgetState extends State<ParentWidget>{
    ...
    Future<dynamic> _fetchData(){..}
    ...
    Widget build(BuildContext){
      return Container(
        ...
       ChildWidget(onRefresh:_fetchData)
       ...
      );
    }
  }

  class ChildWidget extends StatelessWidget{
    ChildWidget({Key? key,this.onRefresh}):super(key:key);
    final Future<dynamic> Function() onRefresh;
    ...
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context){
      return RefreshIndicator(
              onRefresh:onRefresh,
              child:..
      );
    ...
    }
  }
```

The point is to delegate the task of loading the data to a parent **StatefulWidget**'s state so you could use other mechanisms like **ChangeNotifier** to make the parent widget's state call the API and render after calling **setState** future in its own state.